# Asignar una llave foranea de un formulario a otro en django y redireccionar con reverse_lazy

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-urls

Tengo 2 modelos de prueba, Modelo1 y Modelo2. Modelo2 tiene como llave OneToOneField a Modelo1, pero no puedo asignarle el Modelo1_id a Modelo2_id para conservar la relación de los modelos, no sé como acceder a esos datos desde el views.py para asignarlo en form_is_valid, cuando guardo la primer form, no puedo mandarlo con reverse_lazy, ya que debo pasarle la pk, si lo ingreso manualmente a URL, con un select lo pueda asignar, pero creo que eso debería hacerse en el backend

Mis modelos son de:

```
apps/formularios/models.py

class Modelo1(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Modelo2(models.Model):
    relacionModelo1 = models.OneToOneField(Modelo1, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    curp = models.CharField(max_length=18)
    nacionalidad = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

mis forms

```
apps/forms.py

class Modelo1Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Modelo1

        fields = ['nombre', 'apellidos']

        labels = {
            'nombre': 'Nombre(s)',
            'apellidos': 'Apellidos',
        }

        widgets = {
            'nombre': forms.TextInput(),
            'apellidos': forms.TextInput(),
        }


class Modelo2Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Modelo2
        fields = ['relacionModelo1', 'curp', 'nacionalidad']

        labels = {
            'curp': 'CURP',
            'nacionalidad': 'Nacionalidad',
        }

        widgets = {
            'relacionModelo1': forms.HiddenInput(),
            'curp': forms.TextInput(),
            'nacionalidad': forms.TextInput(),
        }
```

Mis views.py

```
class Model1CreateView(CreateView):
    model = Modelo1
    form_class = Modelo1Form
    template_name = 'form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('agregar:formulario2')
    #no se como pasarle la pk a la siguiente página

class Model2CreateView(CreateView):
    #no sé como asiganrle la pk del formulario1 al campo relacionModelo1
    model = Modelo2
    form_class = Modelo2Form
    template_name = 'form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('agregar:formulario1')
```

URL del proyecto

from django.conf.urls import url

```
import views

app_name = "agregar"

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'nuevo1/$', views.Model1CreateView.as_view(), name='formualario1'),
    url(r'nuevo2/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.Model2CreateView.as_view(), name='formulario2'),
]
```

[image: Así se ve cuando accedo a nuevo2 y quiero guardar el formulario]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma sería sobre escribiendo el metodo `form_valid` de cada vista que tengas

1. En el view `Model1CreateView`: para que una vez validado y almacenado el form redirija a la url `agregar:formulario2` con el `pk` del objeto recien creado
2. En el view `Model2CreateView`, para que asigne la relación según lo que recibe por parámetro
3. Se debe excluir del form `Modelo2Form` el campo `relacionModelo1`, ya que lo almacenas dinámicamente en tu view

   ```
   # forms.py

   class Modelo2Form(forms.ModelForm):
       class Meta:
           model = Modelo2
           fields = ['curp', 'nacionalidad']

           labels = {
               'curp': 'CURP',
               'nacionalidad': 'Nacionalidad',
           }

           widgets = {
               'curp': forms.TextInput(),
               'nacionalidad': forms.TextInput(),
           }

   # views.py

   from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
   from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

   class Model1CreateView(CreateView):
       model = Modelo1
       form_class = Modelo1Form
       template_name = 'form.html'
       success_url = None

       #no se como pasarle la pk a la siguiente página
       def form_valid(self, form):
           instance_model1 = form.save(commit=False)
           # other field to save
           instance_model1.save()

           # ya que no tendras un id si no hasta que crees la instancia de modelo1,
           # debes redireccionar con el metodo `HttpResponseRedirect` y generando la url con el metodo `reverse`
           return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('agregar:formulario2', kwargs={'pk': instance_model1.pk}))


   class Model2CreateView(CreateView):
       model = Modelo2
       form_class = Modelo2Form
       template_name = 'form.html'
       success_url = reverse_lazy('agregar:formulario1')

       #no se como asiganrle la pk del formulario1 al campo relacionModelo1
       def form_valid(self, form):
           # creas una instancia, sin salvar, de la clase Modelo2
           instance_model2 = form.save(commit=False)

           # utilizas la instancia de `Modelo1` creada en el metodo post para asiganarle a tu instancia de `Modelo2`
           # esta instancia se crea ya que al `enviar` el formulario, esta sera la accion http que obedece el view
           instance_model2.relacionModelo1 = self.instance_model1
           instance_model2.save()

           # no necesitas un redirect, ya que tomara por defecto la url definida en el parametro `success_url`
           return super(Model2CreateView, self).form_valid(form)

       def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
           self.instance_model1 = get_object_or_404('Modelo1', pk=kwargs.get('pk'))
           return super(Model2CreateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

       def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
           self.instance_model1 = get_object_or_404('Modelo1', pk=kwargs.get('pk'))
           return super(Model2CreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
   ```

Comment: hice la prueba con el código que mencionas, guardo la información, pero me aparece este error al darle registrar      
ImproperlyConfigured at /registrar/nuevo1/
No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model.

Comment: usando     def get_absolute_url(self):
        return u'/registrar/nuevo2/'

Comment: Si agrego el get_absolute_url  y además a la cadena Model1 del Post y Get, la convertí en Modelo para poder acceder a la siguiente página, ya que no recibe str, solo modelo, model manager o queryset me da un error 404. No Modelo1 matches the given query.

Comment: @Kuroi basta con que agregues `success_url = None` en la definición de tu Model1CreateView para evitar el error, no necesitas tener definido una url de redireccion (por error lo deje comentado, ya edite la respuesta), ya que que tu requerimiento te exige redirigir a una url que debes generar posterior a la creación de tu instancia...

Comment: si, ya me redirige a la siguiente página, solo que no asigna el valor al campo, debo pasarlo a visible y asi se ve definido el valor?

Comment: @Kuroi no me había fijado en la definición de tu form `Modelo2Form`, he actualizado mi respuesta, lo que debemos hacer es excluir el campo `relacionModelo1` de tu `Modelo2Form` ya que la asignación la harás dinámicamente en tu view, de esta forma ya se estará salvando tu valor, espero haya sido de ayuda

Comment: muchas gracias, ya ha quedado este experimento, con esto podré aplicarlo en futuros desarrollos